# angularjs can't pass variable to server via url with get method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a global variable 'id'

```
$http.get('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/?id='+id)
  .then(function(rest) {
    alert(id);
  })
```

In this code the `alert` goes fine, showing `id` value, but when I'm not passing the url `console.log` shows `id` as `undefined`.

Why is there a different behavior?

and same time this code working

```
$http.get('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/?id=8')
```

all code

```
   trollm.controller("getSingle",function($scope,$http){
    var id;
    var url;
    $scope.troll=[];
    $scope.init = function(getid)
   {

id=getid; 

//This function is sort of private constructor for controller



//Based on passed argument you can make a call to resource
//and initialize more objects
//$resource.getMeBond(007)
}

$http.get('http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx./?id='+id).then(function(rest) {
  alert(id);

  //alert(id);

      angular.forEach(rest.data, function(singletroll){
      $scope.troll.push(singletroll);
      })
      $scope.lasttrollID=rest.data.lastID;
      //$scope.troll = rest.data;
      })

     console.log($scope.init);
    });
```

Comment: So you are saying the server is not getting the id? Are you sure the server is expecting it to be a get request and not a post?

Comment: yes.. not getting id , but same time if i put number there instead of ID then it working like 

$http.get('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/?id=8')

Comment: You may also want to check your browser console for any Access control allow origin... blah blah phrase

Comment: What is the serverside code doing to read the id?

Comment: iam developing ionic app with angularjs

Comment: Sounds like you are making the request before the variable is assigned

Comment: @charlietfl i set id as globel variable. then why alert getting value ?

Comment: Well if you set that global inside some other code that hasn't run when request runs then before request it would be undefined but request takes time so by then the other code would have run. You need to show all relevant code. All we can do is guess

Comment: @charlietfl  it is already set that's why alert function showing correct value !!! ?

Comment: adding all code ..pls check friends

Comment: Then what you are saying about it being undefined makes no sense. Provide [mcve]

Comment: added all code pls check ..any chance ?

Comment: To me it sounds like `id` isn't what you think it is, and this has nothing to do with $http.get

Comment: Looks like you set id inside `init()` but don't call that until request is complete. None of this is making sense

Comment: @charlietfl okey I set id when it declaring as globel variable. not in any function. still not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling the `$http.get` in the same function instance, right after setting the function constructor var to the controller var.

```
trollm.controller("getSingle",function($scope,$http){
    var id;
    var url;
    $scope.troll=[];

    $scope.init = function(getid){
        // set the controller id
        id=getid; 
        $http.get('http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx./?id='+id).then(function(rest) {
        ...
```

You were not calling the `$http.get` in the init function were you set the `id`. Therefor when the controller was invoked, the id was `undefined`

Comment: success.. thanks broi